# Unable to center logo and text displayed side by side

Tags: html, css

I've tried searching on this issue but I'm still not getting what my problem is. I have a title that consists of a logo and then some title text displayed side by side. I want the pair to be centered on the page. In the following example they are side by side but displayed all the way to the left of the page:

CSS:

```
#header_block {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 80%
    text-align: center;
}

.header_item {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='header_block'>
    <img class='header_item' src="img/logo.png" style="width:80px; height:80px;">
    <h1 class='header_item'>Title Goes Here</h1>
</div>
```

I've tried all sorts of variations but the centering part just isn't working for me. Can you please help shed some light on my confusion? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `margin:auto` requires width to be specified to the container, in your syntax you're missing semicolon `;` after width i don't know may be it will be a typo and apart from that you need to set `vertical-align` css rule to make it rather specific

```
#header_block {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 80%; /*<-- added semi colon*/
    text-align: center;
}
.header_item {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle; /* add this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cjahjh2n/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the missing `;` after your width declaration ?

Adding it, I see no issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to center it horizontally I would just use the following CSS:

```
img{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:80%;
    display:block;
}
.header_item{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header block is moving left because margin-left: auto is putting it there.  If you remove the width property from #header-block, you could then do this:

```
    #header-block {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 50%;   /* centers the header-block's left edge, 
                             but still too far */ 
      left: -159px;       /* accounts for 1/2 the width of inner 
                             content, and moves it back to the 
                             left... now it's centered */
    }
```

Please note, I follow the convention of using hyphens for CSS class names, rather than underscores.

I've created a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/Evply?editors=110) for you.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do -

```
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
```